# Data on the selected days (Mon, Tue, Wed etc.)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL db and using PHP in our local web applicaton for our company. I am trying to make a small stats page which is almost done. But I would like to add another field which shows How many data entered on the days like Monday to Sunday.

I tried many, none of them worked.

Fields: `ID` , `call_time`

*For Example:*

1.

```
SELECT count(*) from tbl_event WHERE w(call_time) = 0
```

2.

```
$TestDay = '2017-01-01'; //For Sunday
SELECT count(*) from tbl_event where call_time = ".$TestDay." 
or (DAYNAME(call_time) = DAYNAME(".$TestDay."))
```

Comment: so you want to know how many records were created on a (say) Friday (in the current year)?

Comment: you can get record for day wise?? may i  right or not @Ayberk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DAYOFWEEK(call_time) AS dayname
FROM tbl_event
WHERE call_time > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(call_time)
```

This will create a list of 5 or 7 days and the number of occurances in the tabel. (limited to the current year, 2017)

You could add a line `AND DAYOFWEEK(call_time) = 5` to limit to certain day

Answer (score 0):

This will provide a summary count of events per day of the week, in the proper order between a range of dates:

```
SELECT 
    dayname(`call_time`) as `Day Of Week`,
    dayofweek(`call_time`) as `DayOrder`,
    count(*) as `num_events`
FROM `tbl_event`
WHERE `call_time` BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-30'
group by dayname(`call_time`)
order by dayofweek(`call_time`)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ivo P 
Thanks for the answer it worked with small touches (;

```
for ($varDay = 1; $varDay <= 7; $varDay++) {
    $Test = "SELECT COUNT(*), DAYOFWEEK(call_time) AS dayname FROM tbl_event WHERE DAYOFWEEK(call_time) = ".$varDay." GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(call_time)";
}
```

Comment: are you sure of the days? DAYOFWEEK(a sunday) equals 1, Saturday = 7

Comment: Due to local settings Monday equals to 1, Sunday equlas to 7.